# How to avoid Xcode 4 adding a width constraint to an NSPopUpButton?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, autolayout, nspopupbutton

The problem here is how to add an `NSPopUpButton` in Xcode 4's Interface Builder pane without IB also adding an (unwanted) width constraint.

In Interface Builder in Xcode 4.3 on Lion using Auto Layout, if you add a normal button to a view, Xcode will add constraints that pin the button to one of the vertical borders and one of the horizontal borders of the view. The width is determined by by the button's intrinsic content size.

If I do the same thing with an `NSPopUpButton`, Interface Builder adds a width constraint to the button, that I can't find a way to get rid of in IB.

I have tried to change the priority of the width constraint (which would suit my intent, as long as I can make it lower than my content compression resistance), but it adds a new one at 1000 immediately.

Any ideas about how to do it in Interface Builder, or do I have to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually turns out that there is a simple solution:

Under the Editor menu, select `Size to Fit Content` (Cmd-=).

Comment: Thanks. Wish I'd seen this answer before I gave up and decided to setup my constraints programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 4 you need to add constraints enough to satisfy layout then remove the ones that are unneeded.

With Xcode 5 it starts out with none so you add then as you go.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this development out. Edited the question to underscore that the issue is with Xcode 4 in the hope that the googling public will be correctly guided.